# how to use pagination in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-pagination

I am using below code for pagination, which I have got from this link.
http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#.V5qvJ-0sjVM
but it is not working for me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//raw.github.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master/lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">Dynamic Content goes here</div>
    <div id="page-selection">Pagination goes here</div>
    <script>
        // init bootpag
        $('#page-selection').bootpag({
            total: 10
        }).on("page", function(event, /* page number here */ num){
             $("#content").html("Insert content"); // some ajax content loading...
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new in jquery. please check this once, and let me know the mistake I am doing.

thanks.

Comment: What error are you receiving? People can't really help you if we don't know what's going on

Comment: It's showing only 2 lines in browser.\n"Dynamic Content goes here
Pagination goes here"\n.

Comment: Error is :- TypeError: $(...).bootpag is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't directly link the *jquery-bootpag* JS file from github.
Either upload it locally to your environment, or change the link to something like:

`//rawgit.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master/lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js`, such that your imports look like this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master/lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Exactly the problem! Download `jquery.bootpag.min.js` locally by simply copy past and save locally.